# Negate the shapely intersection predicate

Tags: python, intersection, geopandas, shapely

I have two [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) geometries:

- 1 [MultiPoint](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#collections-of-points) instance named `multipoints`
- 1 [Polygon](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons) instance named `polygon`

I can compute their [`intersection`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.intersection) by: `multipoints.intersection(polyon)` which results in all points that fall inside the polygon.

I'd like to compute their 'non intersection' to get the points which *doesn't* fall inside the polygon but there is no such: `multipoints.notintersection(polyon)` method:

[image: Wanted result]

I can use the [`symmetric_difference`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.symmetric_difference) as: `multipoints.symmetric_difference(polyon)` but this gives a geometry collection with the points I'm searching for + the whole initial polygon (for which I don't care).

I need to have that done in either one line, or a function that can be plugged into a [lambda function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) for applying it all over the rows of a [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) containing `MultiPoint` geometry instances in each row.

Notice; I can use the boolean result of an [`intersects`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.intersects) inside my lambda but it doesn't seem to work when I apply it on a `GeoDataFrame`:

```
gdf['nonintersectingpoints'] = gdf['my_multipoint_column'].apply(
    lambda multipoints: multipoints if not multipoints.intersects(polygon) \
    else None
)
```

(result is `None` every where).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to basically take the difference between the `multipoints` and the resulting intersection between the `multipoints` and the `polygon`, i.e.: `multipoints.difference(multipoints.intersection(polygon))`

Here is a piece of commented code for understanding:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPoint
import geopandas as gpd

# A Polygon feature
polygon = Polygon([(-0.2, -0.2), (-0.2, 1.2), (1.2, 1.2),
                    (1.2, -0.2), (-0.2, -0.2) ])

# A MultiPoint feature containing severa points:
multipoints = MultiPoint([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1),
                          (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1),
                          (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (-1, -1) ])

# Intersecting features:
inter = multipoints.intersection(polygon)

# Here is the trick to get all the non-intersecting features:
noninter = multipoints.difference(multipoints.intersection(polygon))

# Prepare GeoSeries for plotting:
p = gpd.GeoSeries(polygon)     # the Polygon feature
m = gpd.GeoSeries(multipoints) # the MultiPoint feature
i = gpd.GeoSeries(inter)       # the intersecting features
n = gpd.GeoSeries(noninter)    # the non-intersectiing features

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))
p.plot(color='skyblue', alpha=0.4, ax=ax)
i.plot(color='red', markersize=256, ax=ax)
# Non-intersecting features are show in green:
n.plot(color='lime', markersize=256, ax=ax)
m.plot(color='blue', markersize=16, ax=ax)
plt.grid(zorder=-9)
plt.show()
```

And here is the resulting figure:

[image: Figure resulting of the previous piece of code]

It can also be applied using a lambda as:
`.apply(lambda multipoints: multipoints.difference(multipoints.intersection(poly))`